# Why Bless on Gum if some say not to

Tags: halacha, food, safek, hacham-ovadia-yosef

According to Hacham Ovadia Yosef there is a Halacha of Safek Berachot Lehakel meaning that in any case that there is one (or two I can't remember but it doesn't matter for my example) Posekim that hold not to bless on something we withhold. Why then by flavored gum do we make a Beracha if we have (at least three) Posekim that hold not to: Yaskil Avdi, Yishak Yeranen, and Birkat Hashem? There are probably more just not that I've seen.

Why doesn't Hacham Ovadia apply this rule over here?

Comment: How do you know he doesn't?

Comment: @DoubleAA because it says in Yalkut Yosef in mutliple places that we make a Beracha.

Comment: Which birchas moshe?

Comment: @sam Birkat Hashem by Rabbi Moshe HaLewi.

Comment: Shulchan Aruch 202:15 על הסוקא"ר מברך שהכל וכן המוצץ קנים מתוקות שהכל

Comment: @sam ya because it eventually is all disolved in your mouth but by the gum it is  peice of rubber that you never swallow.

Comment: See http://www.halachayomit.co.il/EnglishDisplayRead.asp?readID=3144 where they explain that Hakham 'Ovadiah didn't hold by Birkat HaShem's proof based on Magen Avraham (i.e. that it was not a valid proof) and therefore rules stringently regarding one reciting a blessing on any food from which one intends to derive enjoyment.

Answer (score -1):

In the Sefer Rivevos Ephraim 7:80:2 he holds that one makes a shehakol on gum because some flavor gets swallows and for thus reason one cannot chew gum on a fast day he also heard this from the Steipler.Then he brings a discussion from Rav Yitzchak Azuli from Yeshivas Porat Yosef who explains the stance of shu"T Yitzchak Yarnein and Yalkut Yosef which is that if one gets some sweetness and its for pleasure of the sweetness then one makes a shakol.see it inside for the back and forth.

http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1084&st=&pgnum=154

Comment: I know why he says to bless but I don't understand why the Deah is not Mevutal because of Safek Berachot.

Comment: Did you see it inside ,he brings the Yabia Omer I believe.

Comment: I read it in Yalkut Yosef the whole Reid.

Comment: I don't see a problem

Comment: What's wrong with my answer?

Comment: It doesn't answer my question.

Comment: I don't understand,Chacham Ovadia explains his reasoning in the source of the Rivevos Ephraim,do you not like his own savarah.

Comment: I read the opinion inside the Sefer Yalkut Yosef before and it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: I meant the Rivevos Ephraim and and the Yabia Omer.

Comment: My question is why we don't apply Safek Berachot Lehakel, not why we bless because of taste.\

Comment: It's volume 6, not 7..